# getting this type in object declaration context

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, c++14

As for the research I've done there is no good method to get the type of the enclosing class in static context. What about non-static context.

example:

```
template<typename TOwner, typename T>
struct prop {
    typedef TOwner Owner;

    prop(TOwner* owner) {
    }
};

struct MyType {
    prop<MyType, short> my_prop = {this};
    prop<decltype(my_prop)::Owner, long> prp = {this};
};
```

This code works, great. But try to replace `MyType` with `decltype(*this)` and it stops working saying this can not be declared in a static context. However `my_prop` can not be considered a static context as well and is more or less in the same context as this (can be rephrased as `this-> my_prop`).

So my question is the following: am I missing something or there really is no way to get type of `this` even in non-static context while declaring property?

Comment: If you're already inside the class, why would you need to deduce the type of the class you're in when you already know?

Comment: I want to make a nice define for properties like `prop<decltype(*this), short> my_prop = {this};` and not specify it in each property.

Comment: The `this` pointer is only available **inside** member functions. It doesn't exist at class scope.

Comment: @BoPersson whey then `prop<MyType, short> my_prop = {this};` works fine? I'm actually wondering if this works, there might be a workaround to pass it further.

Comment: The `{this}` probably counts as being part of a constructor initializer list (a default value), which somehow counts as being inside the constructor.

Comment: @BoPersson `decltype(my_prop)` counts as valid, technically being a shorthand of `decltype(this->my_prop)`

Comment: You are in fact specifying it for each property whether you use decltype or not, since declval just gives you the type of whatever variable/expression you give it. Even if decltype( *this ) worked, it would be no different than writing MyType yourself.

Comment: I meant decltype instead of declval in my previous comment

Comment: Are you against using something like `using self_type = MyType;` and then `prop<self_type, short> my_prop = {this};` ? `self_type` is clear and this idiom could be reused repeatedly.

Comment: `decltype(my_prop)`, in your code, is *not* a shorthand of `decltype(this->my_prop)`.

Comment: @R2-Dequeue, yes. I'm trying to get rid of this verbosity.

Comment: @bku_drytt, no, not the same. With my approach I can do a define, like `#define prop(__type_, __name_) prop<decltype(*this), __type_> __name_ = {this};` which is less verbose and you don't have to repeat your class name all the time

Answer (score 1):

A bit off-topic, but if you are going to store `Owner` pointer in each property member of `Owner`, that is sub-optimal in terms of memory, i.e. each property member has a copy of the very same `Owner*`.

In C++ object layout is known at compile-time, hence, given `this` pointer of a member of `Owner` it is possible to get `Owner*` using [`offsetof` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof), provided the member name is known.

Still, to inject a data member name into `Owner` that data member has to be defined and it takes at least one byte in `Owner`, because C++ does not allow for 0 size data members (unlike empty base class optimization).

Here is an example based on using `offsetof`:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

template<class Owner, class T, class Tag = void>
struct Property;

template<class Owner, class T, class Tag>
Owner& get_property_owner(Property<Owner, T, Tag>&); // Must be overloaded for each individual property of a class.

template<class Owner, class T, class Tag>
inline Owner const& get_property_owner(Property<Owner, T, Tag> const& p) {
    return get_property_owner(const_cast<Property<Owner, T, Tag>&>(p));
}

template<class Owner, class T, class Tag>
struct Property
{
    Property() = default;
    Property(Property const&) = delete;
    Property& operator=(Property const&) = delete;

    template<class U>
    Property& operator=(U&& u) {
        get_property_owner(*this).property_set(*this, std::forward<U>(u));
        return *this;
    }

    operator T() const {
        return get_property_owner(*this).property_get(*this);
    }
};

// Convenience macro to save typing boiler plate code.
#define PROPERTY(Owner, Type, Name) \
struct PropertyName_##Name {}; \
Property<Owner, Type, PropertyName_##Name> Name; \
friend Owner& get_property_owner(Property<Owner, Type, PropertyName_##Name>& p) { \
    return *reinterpret_cast<Owner*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&p) - offsetof(Owner, Name)); \
}

class WithProperties
{
public:
    // Explicitly define a property, begin.
    struct TagA {};

    Property<WithProperties, int, TagA> a;

    template<class T>
    friend WithProperties& get_property_owner(Property<WithProperties, T, WithProperties::TagA>& p) {
        return *reinterpret_cast<WithProperties*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&p) - offsetof(WithProperties, a));
    }

    void property_set(Property<WithProperties, int, TagA>& property_a, int value) {}
    int property_get(Property<WithProperties, int, TagA> const& property_a) const { return 'a'; }
    // Explicitly define a property, end.

    // Define a property using the convience macro, begin.
    PROPERTY(WithProperties, int, b);
    void property_set(Property<WithProperties, int, PropertyName_b>& property_b, int value) {}
    int property_get(Property<WithProperties, int, PropertyName_b> const& property_b) const { return 'b'; }
    // Define a property using the convience macro, end.
};

int main() {
    WithProperties x;
    x.a = 1;
    x.b = 2;
    int a = x.a;
    int b = x.b;
    static_cast<void>(a);
    static_cast<void>(b);
}
```